# Insertion into map<char*, struct _channel*l> channel

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have this map:

```
typedef struct _channel {
    int stuffs;
}channel;
map<char*, struct _channel*> channel
```

But when I use:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(MAX_NAME);
channel* pointer = (channel*)malloc(sizeof(channel));
channel[str] = pointer;
```

I don't get pass through it:

```
// This should've been true, even with find() method
if(channel[str] != 0) {
   // code here
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Show us code that we can reproduce. This question is not answerable as it stands.

Comment: @bitmask I beg to differ

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Your answer is pure conjecture. It doesn't motivate people to ask clear questions.

Comment: @bitmask I guarantee that it is the correct answer. The question is clear enough. Don't be obtuse :)

Comment: BTW you're using a lot of C-isms here. `typedef struct`, `malloc`... best pick up a nice C++ book. :)

Comment: FWIW, don't use `malloc` in C++, unless you are going to follow it up with a call to placement new.  `malloc` doesn't start the lifetime of objects so the accessing any of the members of the struct is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think this has UB. You can begin the lifetime of an object simply by obtaining storage for it (and performing any necessary initialisation, which for a PODdy thing is... none). (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.1)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The bullet you linked to ends with *and* meaning the second bullet also must be met.  `malloc` doesn't do any initialization so it is still UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know what "and" means. You're skipping over the phrases "if any" and "including vacuous initialization"!

Comment: Thanks by the answers

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Also see [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-1.sentence-2).  There is no object there since `malloc` doesn't create objects.

Comment: @NathanOliver That says _"An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, **by an operation that implicitly creates objects (see below)**"_. There's then an example of literally this underneath it (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-12)

Comment: @Nathan: And, in the definition for `malloc`: _"These functions implicitly create objects ([intro.object]) in the returned region of storage and return a pointer to a suitable created object."_. http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#5

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Dang it.  Forgot C++20 fixed that.  That section is not there before C++20.  So, was UB, now not.  Depends on the standard the OP is using.

Comment: @NathanOliver Hmm, I didn't think about that - that's true. It was effectively a defect in the language though, wasn't it? That's what the new wording fixed; all implementations treated it as well-defined, because, well, they have to ;) But yes I will concede it was technically UB until the laundering proposal (and its friends) came along.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Here is the C++17 draft text: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1.  The *by an operation that implicitly creates objects (see below)* part is not there.

Comment: (For any interested readers, we're talking about http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html)

Comment: Yeah, all the compilers did the right thing so it wasn't a big deal, it was just technically UB, the best kind of UB ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver The best and worst at the same time 

Comment: @NathanOliver You win the internet for that Futurama reference :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I decided to drop all of this into the answer since comments have a shelf-life roughly defined by taking the fixed numerical value of the caesium frequency Cs, the unperturbed ground-state hyperfine transition frequency of the caesium-133 atom, to be 9 192 631 770 when expressed in the unit Hz, which is equal to s^–1.

Comment: Thanks. I really should'have use only C in this, but I needed a map. Then I switch to c++ and did this mess.

Answer (score 4):

The default equality comparison for any pointer, including `char*`, is just to literally compare the pointer.

If you have two C-strings, at different locations in memory, with the same contents, comparing pointers to them will not give you the answer you wanted. That's why we use `strcmp` instead when comparing these things.

It's possible to make `std::map` do that, so that lookup works as you intended, but instead you should just use `std::string` as a key; it does this stuff for you.

---

As an aside, you're using a lot of C-isms here. `typedef struct`, `malloc`… Also, you can't create an object with `malloc` before C++20, so your program technically has undefined behaviour, though this was more a standard oversight than anything any implementation ever deliberately took advantage of, so in practice you're likely to be fine ([ref](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html)). Robust, safe, well-defined code is recommended regardless.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct channel
{
    int stuff;
};

std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<channel>> channels;

int main()
{
    channel["key"] = std::make_unique<channel>();
    
    // ...
    
    if (channel["key"] != nullptr)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

You probably don't need the pointer indirection at all; you can likely just store `channel`s in the map as values.

If not, because code elsewhere needs to "own" the `channel`s too, `std::shared_ptr` is your friend.

Comment: `if (channel["key"] != nullptr)` should be replaced with `if (channel.find("key") != channel.end())` or `if (channel.count("key") != 0)` instead.  `std::map::operator[]` will insert a new default-constructed element if the requested key is not found, and you don't want to clutter your `map` with `nullptr`s over time. Unless storing `nullptr` is a real possibility, in which case you would need something more like this instead: `auto it = channel.find("key"); if (it != channel.end() && it->second != nullptr)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would generally agree, but I'm trying not to deviate from the OP's intent, only correct their "style".